# Resizing video to a particular position in screen android

Tags: android

**What I have**: I have a video view displaying a video

**What I am trying to achieve**: I am trying to resize the video by modifying height of container relative layout.

**What is happening**: The video gets resized, but it is like this below

```
 ----------------------------------------------------------
|                 |                                        |
|                 |                                        |
|                 |                                        |
|                 |                                        |
|                 |                                        |
|                 |                                        |
|-----------------                                         |
|                                                          |
|                                                          |
|                                                          |
 ----------------------------------------------------------
```

**What I am trying to achieve:**

```
 ----------------------------------------------------------
|                                         |                |
|                                         |                |
|                                         |                |
|                                         |                |
|                                         |                |
|                                         |                |
|                                         |----------------|
|                                                          |
|                                                          |
|                                                          |
 ----------------------------------------------------------
```

***Smaller square is the video***

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/rootParent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/third_shape"
            android:id="@+id/addForLShape" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="right">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:id="@+id/activity_main"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <VideoView
                    android:id="@+id/video"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </FrameLayout>
```

**Code:**

```
 activity_main.getLayoutParams().width = calcWidth;
            activity_main.getLayoutParams().height = calcHeight;
            activity_main.requestLayout();
```

Comment: what is `activity_main`?

Answer (score 0):

try to call `requestLayout();` on parent layout of your resized layout